# How to ensure Facebook sharing sdk posts to Facebook timeline when posting from my app

Tags: ios, facebook, sharing

I am creating a dynamic shareable image from my app that I'd like to share to Facebook using their Sharing sdk. I have followed all the instructions to set up my app with Facebook as per their guidelines. My particular problem is coming in where I am rendering out a view from my app and sending it through to Facebook.

The image is rendered out perfectly and even appears in the ShareDialog that opens up. When trying to post to my timeline/news feed a progress circle appears and then before completion just hands over control back to my app. I can only complete the process if I am sharing the image to a group I am the admin of. This leads me to believe it may be some sort of permission problem.

Any help would be much appreciated

Here is part of my code for when a user clicks to share a card from within the app:

```
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent();
SharePhoto[] photos = new SharePhoto[1];
photos[0] = SharePhoto.From(e.image, false);
content.Photos = photos;

ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog();
shareDialog.SetShareContent(content);
shareDialog.Mode = ShareDialogMode.Automatic;
shareDialog.Show();
```

Comment: Facebook removed the permissions that allow to upload a photo onto a personal profile via API a while ago, so my guess would be that this is directly related.

Comment: Update! So I tried using the Facebook ShareSheet instead of a ShareDialog and everything seems to have worked ok. Maybe a problem within the Facebook app.